# woocommerce hide fields for non-logged-in users

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to make a function where non-logged-in users won't see the product price, add to cart and description text. At the moment I am using the plugin hide price until login so the price wont show. I am also using this css code:

```
body.logged-in form.cart, body.logged-in div.woocommerce-product-details__short-description, body.logged-in div.product_meta { display:none; }
```

This was the only code I could find on the internet and for me it is working the other way round. If someone can help that would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code snippet to hide price, add to cart and short description..

```
add_action( 'init', 'hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in' );

function hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in() { 
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {       
// Remove Add to cart from shop page
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
// Remove Price from shop page
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
// Remove Add to cart from single product page     
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
// Remove price from single product page
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
//Remove short description (excerpt) from single product page
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );  
}
}
```

And below code snippet if you want to remove description tab from single product page for non logged in users

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'remove_product_description_tab', 98 );
function remove_product_description_tab( $tabs ) {
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {       
    unset( $tabs['description'] );
}
    return $tabs;
}
```